# How can I receive data from firebase under a certain variable in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to receive data from realtime database every time when I load the page. I don't know why it's not working. I am trying to receive data under the word "email". I don't know how to do this with a variable because firebase doesn't let me do this. But can you help me with receiving the data?

Thank you!

```js
$('.save').on('click', function() {
  var Email = localStorage.getItem("email");
  window.alert(Email)
  todoArray = [];

  for (i = 1; i < 25; i++) {
    let todoValue = $('#' + i).val();

    let todoObject = {
      todoHour: i,
      todoItem: todoValue
    }

    firebase.database().ref('email').set({
      todoArray
    });
    todoArray.push(todoObject);
  }
})
// save data

const issuesRef = firebase.database().ref('email');

function loadTodos() {
  issuesRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(snap => {
      const issue = snap.val();
      todoObject = issue
    })
  })
}

//get data
```